# Limited Duration Alimony - do I need to do anything to stop the payments after the period ends?

Tags: family-law, divorce, child-support

My ex-wife was granted LDA for 10 years, which ends in December 2020. Do I need to do anything -fill any paperwork, etc.- to stop the payments or do they stop automatically?

Both, my child support payments and my alimony payments are automatically deducted from my paycheck bi-weekly. My divorce was in New Jersey.

Comment: Hi @Icarus, can you please revise your question to be generalized vs requesting legal advice?

Comment: Hello @Andrew - I am not looking for legal advice; I am simply asking whether the LDA needs additional paperwork when the end date is reached or whether the payments stop automatically after the end date is reached. I am not trying to end the LDA in advance or modify it in any way. Thanks!